# MSAL Client Credential with AAD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I want to allow users of a B2C-secured app to browse before deciding to register

To that end, I need to embed a Client Credential flow within my app

I have only been able to find examples dealing with Graph API, which is an invalid token for an API secured within my AAD

Would someone be able to modify the example below to indicate what the Client Credential Paramaters would look like below in respect of b2clogin in order to pass it an app ID, and secret, and return a token which can be used to authorise calls to the API?

Edit: this is what I am now passing to try and get a token I can use

```
    public static string tenantID = "aadtenant.onmicrosoft.com";
    public static string ClientID = "xxxx-a2e2-40f5-958b-dc39ca2bd413";
    public static string Secret = "zzzzzzzzs_JhPY1HSFEREgRy5Z2rcL";
    public static string redirectURI = "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api";
    public static string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://xxxxxx-a2e2-40f5-958b-dc39ca2bd413/.default" };
    public static string url = String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenantID);
```

However this returns a failure

```
Exception AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.
```

The one thing I have noticed is that when I set up API access in my AAD tenant app, only Graph is assigned. When I go to My APIs, I am not seeing anything. So I am not sure how exactly the AAD app and the B2C app relate to each other

Another edit: I have now granted a permission from the AAD app to the B2C app and created a scope but I am still getting an error, this time that the scope isn't valid

Comment: `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/aadtenant.onmicrosoft.com"` is not a tenant id. `"aadtenant.onmicrosoft.com"` would be.

Comment: Ok, I've made the edit but it returns the same error as before

Comment: This is supported now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/client-credentials-grant-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I implemented client credentials authentication to an API where B2C was used,
I essentially had to add a second authentication scheme to the API.
I registered an app in the underlying Azure AD of the B2C tenant,
registered an application permission there (appRole),
and then that can be assigned to client apps (that also need to be registered in the underlying AAD tenant).

Then the API needs to be able to validate both access tokens coming in with scopes from the B2C registration,
or with app permissions (roles) from the AAD registration.
The issuers etc. are different in those tokens.

It is a bit painful frankly, but this is essentially what the docs recommend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/application-types#daemonsserver-side-applications.

> Although client credential flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C, you can set up client credential flow using Azure AD. An Azure AD B2C tenant shares some functionality with Azure AD enterprise tenants. The client credential flow is supported using the Azure AD functionality of the Azure AD B2C tenant.

Once you have all that setup, your client needs to use the AAD registration client id + secret, with the scope set to `api-client-id/.default`.

Comment: I've tried to work my way through that guide. I've done everything it asked and am now trying to generate a token in Postman. Could you clarify what format the URL should look like for scopes please, as I am alternately getting MSAL errors which either say resource principal not found, or no tenant identifier has been passed (depending on the URL I pass it)

Comment: @junnas Note the error only occurs when I change the graph URI to be what I think it wants for the AAD app I created, in order to return a token that can be used to access the B2C app

Comment: You would send the token request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-b2c-tenant-guid/oauth2/v2.0/token`. You can find the tenant GUID in the Azure Portal from Azure Active Directory -> Properties.

Comment: I'm already doing that - the question I had related to the scope value. I can only get a token when I use graph, which is no use to me, above you said to put in the client ID + "./default" but I just want to know exactly what that full URL looks like as everything I try (Except graph) results in an error. Having said that, graph is the only API that my AAD app has permissions for - when I go to grant API permissions, and select My APIs, I get "none found"

Comment: The scope could be e.g. `187f0772-e44f-429b-a310-6712cd659f35/.default`. Alternatively if your app has an App ID URI, you could use that + '/.default'. Both should be valid though.

Comment: I figured that's what you meant and had already tried but it results in this: "Exception AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials."

Comment: I have updated the original description of the issue to match where I am after making those changes to see if there's anything you can see...

Comment: Can you recall if you needed to have two apps in the AAD directory? It's been suggested to me the reason my code fails with anything other than the graph as the scope is because otherwise it's calling itself?

Comment: Yes, you do need to register the calling app as well :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209912/discussion-between-journeyman1234-and-juunas).